# Unicode error for opening path towards HTML file, Python. How would I fix?

Tags: python, html, folium

I'm using `Folium` to create a map and display it as an HTML file. I created a function to open up the HTML file with the given path.

```
import webbrowser
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

m = folium.Map([52.5, 2], zoom_start=5.5)
display(m)
m.save('map.html')


def auto_open(path):
    html_page = f'{path}'
    m.save(html_page)
    # open in browser.
    new = 2
    webbrowser.open(html_page, new=new)


auto_open('C:\Users\Student\PycharmProjects\World Map')
```

I'm getting the error code:
`auto_open('C:\Users\Student\PycharmProjects\World Map') ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

It's the correct path to the html file. But I'm not understanding the error at all. I would love the help. Any more information I can give let me know. Thank you.

Edit: I added in the `\\` to fix the error, but now I'm getting, I've done this and it pops up:

`File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 161, in save fid = open(outfile, 'wb') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:\\Users\\Student\\PycharmProjects\\World Map'`

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image. And don't put it in comment.

Comment: BTW: instead of `html_page = f'{path}'` you can do `html_page = path`

Comment: char \ has special meaning in strings (even in path) and `\U...` means `unicode` - so use \\ - `'C:\\Users\\Student\\PycharmProjects\\World Map'` or use prefix `r` to create raw string 
`r'C:\Users\Student\PycharmProjects\World Map'`

Answer (score 2):

You need nothing but doubled parentheses to replace the single ones :

```
auto_open('C:\\Users\\Student\\PycharmProjects\\World Map')
```

P.S: Don't forget to close up the target file(*outfile*) before re-run in order not to prevent getting *[Errno 13]*

Comment: @Axhul try to close the source file before running

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's not open at all or anything.

Comment: you're trying to write to an outfile, and most probably it's still open before run, isn't it? @Axhul

Comment: If you mean opening the file outside of my computer like on the web then yes. If not I don't know.